# replace all occurrences after nth occurrence php?

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have this string...

```
$text = "1|2|1400|34|A|309|Frank|william|This|is|the|line|here|"
```

How do I replace all the occurrences of | with " " after the **8th** occurrence of | from the beginning of the string?

I need it look like this, `1|2|1400|34|A|309|Frank|william|This is the line here`

```
$find = "|";
$replace = " ";
```

I tried

```
$text = preg_replace(strrev("/$find/"),strrev($replace),strrev($text),8);
```

but its not working out so well. If you have an idea please help!

Comment: Using regex is NOT the way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$text = '1|2|1400|34|A|309|Frank|william|This|is|the|line|here|';
$repl = preg_replace('/^([^|]*\|){8}(*SKIP)(*F)|\|/', ' ', $text);
//=> 1|2|1400|34|A|309|Frank|william|This is the line here
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dT9iU3/1)

Approach is to match and ignore first 8 occurrences of `|` using `^([^|]*\|){8}(*SKIP)(*F)` and the replace each `|` by space.

Comment: This is amazing bro and Regex101.com is awesome btw thank you! I just tested it and it's working exactly like you say it should. I'll walk through the explination and learn why this is working. Thanks again so much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. Take a look at `EXPLANATION` section on top-right of regex101 demo for a detailed explanation of regex.

Comment: Love it :) I look for this since a while. For people using `r` and the function `gsub`, use perl=T``. E.g. `gsub("^([^!]*!){2}(*SKIP)(*F)|!", "|", t, perl=T)` if you wanna replace after the 2nd occurence **!** with **|**. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explode()`

```
$text = "1|2|1400|34|A|309|Frank|william|This|is|the|line|here|";
$arr = explode('|', $text);
$result = '';
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    if($k == 0) $result .= $v;
    else $result .= ($k > 7) ? ' '.$v : '|'.$v;
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex also and replace the matched `|` with a single space.

```
$text = '1|2|1400|34|A|309|Frank|william|This|is|the|line|here|';
$repl = preg_replace('~(?:^(?:[^|]*\|){8}|(?<!^)\G)[^|\n]*\K\|~', ' ', $text);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dA7uN1/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $text = "1|2|1400|34|A|309|Frank|william|This|is|the|line|here|";
    $texts = explode( "|", $text );
    $new_text = '';
    $total_words = count( $texts );
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $total_words; $i++)
    { 
        $new_text .= $texts[$i];
        if ( $i <= 7 )
            $new_text .= "|";
        else
            $new_text .= " ";
    }

    echo $new_text;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that is:

```
$text = "1|2|1400|34|A|309|Frank|william|This|is|the|line|here|";
$arr = explode('|', $text, 9);
$arr[8] = strtr($arr[8], array('|'=>' '));
$result = implode('|', $arr);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Example without regex:

```
$text = "1|2|1400|34|A|309|Frank|william|This|is|the|line|here|";
$array = str_replace( '|', ' ', explode( '|', $text, 9 ) );
$text = implode( '|', $array );
```

**str_replace:**

> If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed with
>   every entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well.

**explode:**

> If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a
>   maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of
>   string.